# how to get the data in the datastore of App Engine by url

Tags: google-app-engine, url, datastore

in Google App Engine,after using the makePersistent() to store the data in the datastore,i know how to get the data content by the key using getObjectById().
but now i wanna to  get the data in the datastore by url. i think the url is created .
so the question is how the url can be created to get the data in the datastore

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in means to access the datastore through URLs. If you choose to, your application can implement URLs that return data from the datastore.

Comment: thanks.i know i should implement urls to return data ,but can you tell me how to implement urls? or can you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to take a look at [titan-files](http://code.google.com/p/titan-files/). It's a powerful file-system abstraction on top of the DataStore and/or blob store. I'm using it for a commercial application and so far I've been very happy with it.